# Are there any Implementations of Secure Indexes?

Tags: encryption, implementation, database, secure-index

There are several papers about `Secure Indexes`, for Example "[Searchable Symmetric Encryption:
Improved Definitions and Efficient Constructions](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/210.pdf)" and "[Secure Indexes](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~eujin/papers/secureindex/secureindex.pdf)".

I'm trying to build a system, that uses secure indexes to store and search data. Are there any existing solutions out there which implement these types of schemes?

Comment: Am curious , if you made any progress.

Comment: This question is hard to answer. Clearly no one on here knows of a publically available implementation or they would have answered. That said, no one is apparently willing to say that one doesn't exist (and rightfully so). You've put us in a difficult position :)

Comment: That sounds like you've a non public available solution mikeazo ;) Since I wasn't able to find something like that, I've developed such a system as part of my Bachelor Thesis. The result is a running database, that is built on top of Apache Solr that is very fast in searching text (search time of O(1)). Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the results, because I've developed this system for Atos Worldline and I'm still working on improving it and find business cases for it. But if anyone is interested, feel free to contact me for further details.

Answer (score 2):

[Cryptdb](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) has a search component which implements techniques from this [paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~dawnsong/papers/se.pdf) this might be helpful to get some insights and get started , cryptdb is open sourced code is available

Comment: This looks interesting. The problem I see here, Cryptdb isn't specialized in text search. Since this is the key feature of indexes, it would be very nice to have ;)